# getting error when I use destructuring assignment to simplify my props

Tags: javascript, reactjs, destructuring

I'm working on destructuring on all props in this component. When I store all my props using a variable assignment the code works, but when I store my props in the function parameters I get an error message.Why does this happen? My component along the error message are down below.

```js
import React from 'react';
import Counter from './Counter.js';

const Player = ( { id, name, score, changeScore, index } ) => {
/*const { id, name, score, changeScore, index } = props*/
  return (
    <div className="player">
      <span className="player-name">
        <button className="remove-player" onClick={() => props.removePlayer(id)}>✖</button>
        { name }
      </span>

      <Counter
      score={score}
      changeScore={changeScore}
      index={index}
      />
    </div>
  );
}

export default Player;
```

[image: error message from browser]

Answer (score 2):

```
<button className="remove-player" onClick={() => props.removePlayer(id)}>✖</button>
```

`props` isn't defined because instead of doing:

```
const Player = ( props ) => {
```

You're doing:

```
const Player = ( { id, name, score, changeScore, index } ) => {
```

### Possible solutions

**1. Add `...props` at the end of your parameter destructuring:**

```
const Player = ( { id, name, score, changeScore, index, ...props } ) => {
```

Then you can use `props.removePlayer()`:

```
<button className="remove-player" onClick={() => props.removePlayer(id)}>✖</button>
```

**2. As Emile suggests, add `removePlayer` to the parameter destructuring:**

```
const Player = ( { id, name, score, changeScore, index, removePlayer} ) => {
```

Then you use `removePlayer()` instead of `props.removePlayer()`:

```
<button className="remove-player" onClick={() => removePlayer(id)}>✖</button>
```

Comment: The solution being to add `removePlayer` in the destructured parameters.

Comment: fixed it. had to add the removePlayer prop to the parameters, then change the syntax inside the button element. got rid of the of variable assignment. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

```
const Player = ( { id, name, score, changeScore, index, removePlayer } ) => {
/*const { id, name, score, changeScore, index } = props*/
  return (
    <div className="player">
      <span className="player-name">
        <button className="remove-player" onClick={() => removePlayer(id)}>✖</button>
        { name }
      </span>

      <Counter
      score={score}
      changeScore={changeScore}
      index={index}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

try this I hope this works
removePlayer must be destructured